The minimum time to evaluate an arithmetic expression.
I have an arithmetic expression and I want to find the minimum time to compute this expression knowing the delay of each operator. The operators are addition, subtraction, multiplication, and exponentiation.
I'm also eager to know the solution in a sequential environment, where only one operator can be evaluated at a time, and a parallel environment, where any number of operators can be evaluated simultaneously provided that their operands have been computed before.
I know how to find the minimum time if the order of evaluating operators is fixed, but that is not the case. The difficulty of the problem rise from the too many possible ways to compute an expression.
For instance, consider the expression:
$(a \times a+b \times b)+(a \times b+a \times b)$.
One way to evaluate this expression is as follows. It takes $3t_{mul}+3t_{add}$ sequentially and $t_{mul}+2t_{add}$ in parallel:

$a \times a$,
$b \times b$,
$a \times b$,
$a\times a + b \times b$,
$a \times b + a \times b$, and
($a\times a + b \times b$)+ ($a \times b + a \times b$).

It can also be evaluated in this way, which takes $t_{add}+t_{mul}$ both sequentially and in parallel:

$a+b$, and
$(a+b) \times (a+b)$.

This is not just about factoring. For instance, consider another example: $a^{b+c}$.
One way takes $t_{add}+t_{exp}$ both sequentially and in parallel:

$b+c$, and
$a^{b+c}$.

The other way takes $2t_{exp}+t_{mul}$ sequentially and $t_{exp}+t_{mul}$ in parallel.

$a^b$
$a^c$
$a^b \times a^c$

I think I should exhaust the whole search space but I haven't come to a structured approach to do so. I'm also open to a solution that suggest using a previously developed tool, etc.
Thank you

This is a very difficult problem. Even minimizing multiplications to compute powers is a very difficult question, already asked here. I recommend that you read the answer proposed by Bill Dubuque.
See also OEIS sequence A003313 (Length of shortest addition chain for n), the Achim Flammenkamp's web page on addition chains or Addition Chains.

Thank you for your response. I think you're correct in the sequential environment but not in the parallel environment. Even for the addition chain problem, If you consider using two adders, you can solve the problem in $\log_2(n)$ step. Am I right?

Also, for the sequential environment, I'm not necessarily seeking a polynomial-time solution. I'm seeking a previously-implemented approach to solve this problem, even if it is an exhaustive search.
